# PHP - How to fix I/O function calls should not be vulnerable to path injection attacks in Real World?

Tags: php, security, owasp

I have below code coming up as security vulnerability in SonarQube.

[image]

It's a website php script runs by the internal users to convert a HTML file to a PDF file, User gives the output filename, And program saves it as PDF from the given user filename.

```
  if(!empty($_GET["output_file"]) && is_string($_GET["output_file"]) && strlen($$_GET["output_file"]) > 0 ) {
      $outfile =  (string) rawurldecode($_GET["output_file"]);
      file_put_contents($outfile, $dompdf->output());
  }
```

it says to resolve it via

**The mitigation strategy should be based on the whitelisting of allowed paths or characters.**

I am not sure how can i verify a whitelist characters or path that is given by the user as a String. How to solve this issue?

Any other work around on this? Without eliminating the fact that User must supply his output filename. (We can't use standard filename as the output file due to user requirement).

Comment: `rawurldecode` is not needed, unless you are double encoding, `The GET variables are passed through urldecode().` The `is_string` won't help, anything malicious would be a string. Check that the path is alphanumerical, don't think user can do much by just changing name. Currently something like `../../` could start navigating across system. I would not allow naming by parameters.

Comment: The least thing you should do, regarding the possibility of path traversal using `../`, is apply [`realpath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to the value, and then check if the result starts with a base path you consider "save", so that no upload can manage to "break out" of that and get itself stored anywhere further up.